# Unexpected outgoing SSH TCP packets

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall, iptables

I have a small VPS with the following IPTables rules:

```bsh
*filter

:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]

:f2b-ssh - [0:0]
:f2b-sshd - [0:0]

# Allow incoming SSH.
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing SSH to port 22.
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow all response packets.
# Accept forwarding of all response packets.
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Special rule for logging weird outgoing SSH packets <---- HERE
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[SSH_OUTPUT_debug]: " --log-level 7

# Reject any packets which don't fit the rules above...
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT

-A f2b-ssh -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN

COMMIT
```

Every now and then, some weird outgoing SSH packets seem to pop up in my logs, and I cannot figure out where they come from.
I don't think they are just an attempted response to an ssh connection attempt, since I only register about a dozen of these in a week (and I get thousands of ssh login attempts per month).

They're also not just regular outgoing ssh attempts by me: any outgoing ssh connection made by me works just fine, and does not get registered in my logs; furthermore, I have never attempted connecting to those IPs (since they don't belong to me).

I have no reason to suspect that my VPS has been compromised so far (I only use ssh key auth). What could be the source of these odd TCP packets showing up in my logs? Has my server been compromised? Is my understanding of the rules wrong? Or are these some kind of spoofed packets coming from the outside?

```
[SSH_OUTPUT_debug]: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=my.vps.ip.x DST=175.139.201.77 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60227 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=39829 WINDOW=227 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
[SSH_OUTPUT_debug]: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=my.vps.ip.x DST=203.106.103.129 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=23755 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=58792 WINDOW=227 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0 
[SSH_OUTPUT_debug]: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=my.vps.ip.x DST=121.46.27.10 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54345 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=51662 WINDOW=227 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
[SSH_OUTPUT_debug]: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=my.vps.ip.x DST=114.116.143.41 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=46056 WINDOW=28960 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
[SSH_OUTPUT_debug]: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=my.vps.ip.x DST=103.231.4.198 LEN=81 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=55949 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=59049 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
[SSH_OUTPUT_debug]: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=my.vps.ip.x DST=86.21.205.149 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=42840 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=36050 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

Comment: Looks pretty much like someone who just wants to connect and your server answering that connect request. You can ignore that, they usually scan the entire IPv4 spectrum multiple time a day and try to exploit any insecure devices. You using SSH Public Key Authentication pretty much resolves any risk of being compromised.

Comment: Please note how the *source* port (on your VPS’ end) is 22, not the destination port.

Comment: Any update on this sorcery? I'm getting from time to time the same output `[iptables-drop-output] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=server.ip DST=105.5.5.5 LEN=364 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=28728 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=55305 WINDOW=503 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0`

Comment: @DrBeco I think the answer is in [comment #10](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1215927#c10) from the first link in the accepted answer. Basically whoever is doing the ssh scanning never bothers to finalize closing the TCP connection, and just leaves it hanging. This results in our outgoing packets to get dropped by the firewall because the connection isn't tracked on our side anymore (because it went into timeout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A half open connection will timeout (presumed closed) in conntrack unilaterally, it does not wait past the timeout. It if it takes longer the related packets are no longer recognised as related and are flagged as you see. It's a known issue, some discussion below:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1215927

https://lists.netfilter.org/pipermail/netfilter/2005-August/062059.html

Comment: I think this might be it. I've just looked at my auth.log and fail2ban.log, and some (though not all of them) of these packets seem to show up right after a failed ssh connection attempt (like invalid cipher), or right after fail2ban bans them

Answer (score 1):

I note that they're all FINs. I bet this is a case of iptables and the TCP stack having different ideas of the state of a connection that's in the process of being closed.

Maybe the TCP stack had queued a FIN, but before it got sent, a RST had come in from the far end. So now because of the RST, iptables no longer considers the connection established, so the FIN gets logged.

A full packet capture of one of these sessions would probably reveal exactly what's going on.

Comment: Interesting, I had not noticed the flags. I've looked into the logs, and it seems that most packets are FIN, but there are a few SYN and PSH packets as well (I have added them in the examples at the end).
Thank you for your suggestion, I will try to capture a few packets and see if I get anything useful out of those

Comment: I think it could still be iptables and TCP disagreeing about connection state due to RSTs coming in just as other packets were queued to go out. If getting packet captures is problematic, try just logging every incoming RST to port 22, and see if there's a corresponding incoming RST just before every weird outgoing logged packet.

Comment: I tried logging all RST packets on port 22.

`-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 3/min -j NFLOG --nflog-group 3
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 --tcp-flags RST RST -m limit --limit 3/min -j NFLOG --nflog-group 3`

Result: only a few outgoing RST packets from me to the outside, and no correspondence between any of these and the other stuff I've seen so far.
However, looking at my auth.log and fail2ban.log, there are some (not all) matches between failed connection attempts (typically invalid cyphers) or fail2ban bans, and the outgoing packets (both RST and others)